# Number of threads constantly rising ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, threadpool

I have .net core web api application run on IIS. In some part of application I call wcf service for some information (asynchronous, use async await, etc) Sometimes that wcf service is unavailable and I get timeout (default is 1 minute) and then start problem. Because there's a lot of request for my API, and so on on wcf service, number of threads start to rise, at some point wcf service start to work normaly, but when my number of threads is over 200(I gues) it's start to rise constantly (1 thread per second, I guess) and it wont stop. My application is useless then and only way is to stop and start application pool on IIS, and my applications start to work normaly.

This is case one in a month, but I don't know what to do. I tried and chek a lot. Next try is to lower timeout when calling wcf service.

Comment: What does *your code* do? ASP.NET Core won't start spinning up threads for no reason. Somehow *your* code is blocking those threads. If you use `async/await` with WCF's asynchronous methods, the threads won't be blocked while waiting

Comment: If you *know* that the remote service is broken, a good idea would be to just stop using it. You can implement the code yourself or use eg [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to implement policies like retrying or stop using a service

Comment: I think we can do it this way: 1.Adjust the maximum number of threads on the server. 2.Set startup priority, priority WCF program. 3.Remove useless programs.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the CircuitBreaker-pattern could help you?

*The basic idea behind the circuit breaker is very simple. You wrap a protected function call in a circuit breaker object, which monitors for failures. Once the failures reach a certain threshold, the circuit breaker trips, and all further calls to the circuit breaker return with an error, without the protected call being made at all.*

Read more at: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html

Comment: @p It would not queue up a lots of requests to the wcf-service when the wcf service is down.

Comment: The circuit breaker is useful only when the service you want to call is known to have failed permanently, so you can stop using it. With most remote services though you'd want to *retry* instead of abandoning the service. You'd only use a circuit breaker if repeated retries showed that the failure is permanent

Comment: Its so much we dont know in this case, but I think it could be a good idea to fail the calls without calling the wcf service when its not responding.